# Dangers of Unconventional UIViewController Usage

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm going through some old code and trying to detect some hard to find bugs.  I came across an unusual usage of a UIViewController where the controller is allocated, stored in a property, and its view is added as a subview instead of presenting the entire controller.

Let me start off by saying I know this is kind of hacky and abnormal.  That said, what are the dangers in the following implementation?  Are there any unexpected side effects that this could cause?  What if `MyOtherViewController` unloads its view and recreates it due to receiving a memory warning at some point, could that cause any strange behavior?

```
@interface MyViewController()
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyOtherViewController *otherVC;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.otherVC = [[MyOtherViewController alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:self.otherVC.view];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Displaying a View Controllers Contents Programatically

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH6-SW8

Note this:  Important: Never install the view controller’s view into a view hierarchy directly.

Comment: The note that basically says never do it the way I am doing it is very straightforward, good find.  I ended up taking a very close look at Apple's "Creating Custom Container View Controllers" guide, found here, and implementing things like that: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is creating custom view controller containers. This is not a bad thing, but you aren't doing it the way you're supposed to. There is a [section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81) in UIViewController's class reference that explains exactly how to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: I like this answer in that it points me to how this could/should be done, but it really doesn't address my question about the dangers (if any) of doing what I did above.  +1, but cannot accept as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just tracked down a nasty BAD EXEC crash in a project I moved to (see nasty bug below).

I can say that using a UIViewController is very bad because:

- You have to make sure the controller is not deallocated. The view won't because it is in view hierarchy with a superview, but the controller has no object to retain it. If it was added to the window as a rootController, to a tab controller, a navigation controller or presented by another controller (normal usage) it would be ok.
- It won't receive orientation changes and messages that you would expect to get called besides viewDidLoad.
- Nasty bugs. For instance in iOS 5 if this controller is not deallocated before you dismiss a modal controller you'll have a BAD EXEC crash that will drive you crazy. It seems the animation methods from the SDK expect your view controller to be present during the dismiss modal animation.